# Remove tag synonym [liskov-substitution] -> [lsp]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

[The lsp tag is ambiguous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63849/tag-lsp-has-no-wiki-info-and-no-one-will-be-able-to-provide-it), and should probably not be used at all. Currently [it has three synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lsp/synonyms), which means that if someone tags a question as "liskov-substitution" it will actually get the less-useful tag "lsp".